# Finding factors that correspond to more than one values

Tags: r, replace, data-cleaning

Suppose, that one has the following dataframe:

```
x=data.frame(c(1,1,2,2,2,3),c("A","A","B","B","B","B"))
names(x)=c("v1","v2")

x
  v1 v2
1  1  A
2  1  A
3  2  B
4  2  B
5  2  B
6  3  B
```

In this dataframe a value in `v1` I want to correspond into a label in `v2`. However, as one can see in this example `B` has more than one corresponding values.

Is there any elegant and fast way to find which labels in `v2` correspond to more than one values in `v1` ?

The result I want ideally to show, the values - which in our example should be `c(2,3)` - as well as the row number - which in our example should be `r=c(5,6)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that we want the index of the unique elements in 'v1' grouped by 'v2' and that should have more than one unique elements, we create a logical index with `ave` and use that to subset the rows of 'x'.

```
i1 <- with(x, ave(v1, v2, FUN = function(x) 
    length(unique(x))>1 & !duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE)))!=0
x[i1,]
#   v1 v2
#5  2  B
#6  3  B
```

---

Or a faster option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(x)[, .I[uniqueN(v1)>1 & !duplicated(v1, fromLast=TRUE)], v2]$V1
x[i1, 'v1', with = FALSE][, rn := i1][]
#   v1 rn
#1:  2  5
#2:  3  6
```

Comment: if at the end all values are indeed correspond to a unique number, `x[i1,]` should be filled with `NA` ?? I tried it, but it returns NA.

Comment: @msh855  I am not sure what you meant.  Based on your description, you wanted the rows 5 and 6. `The result I want ideally to show, the values - which in our example should be c(2,3) - as well as the row number - which in our example should be r=c(5,6)`

Comment: yes, that's true. But, I don't understand when I tried this into my original dataframe the index i1 is filled with NA.

Comment: @msh855 Do you have NA elements in your original dataset?  If you have NA elements, try `i1 <- setDT(x)[, .I[uniqueN(v1)>1 & !duplicated(v1, fromLast=TRUE) & !is.na(v1)], v2]$V1; x[i1, 'v1', with = FALSE][, rn := i1][]`